# How to get value in oracle database with this query

Tags: database, oracle

I have 1 record value : CS201508110000001 and i want to select value to get 0000001 + 1 only with this query :

```
SELECT substr(NVL(to_char(MAX(COLUMN_NAME)+1,'FM0000000'),'0000001'),-7) AS COLUMN_NAME from TABLE_NAME
```

But, i got error `invalid number` in my sql. Im using oracle for my database. Thank You

**Edit :
Works now with this query :**

```
SELECT nvl(to_char(MAX(substr(PX_IR536_COMPLN_NO, -7) + 1), 'FM0000000'), '0000001') AS PX_IR536_COMPLN_NO from IR536
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT nvl(to_char(substr(COLUMN_NAME, -7) + 1, 'FM0000000'), '0000001') from TABLE_NAME;
```